# How to add two string arrays to a custom listview?

Tags: android, listview, arrays

I have a custom `ListView` with two `TextViews`, I have two string arrays in my class how can I add these two string arrays as items for my `ListView`?  Each representing one textview.
Thank you.

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6383330/how-to-combine-two-array-list-and-show-in-a-listview-in-android

Comment: @HirenDabhi I've edited my question please check it my question is different.

Comment: check this http://codehenge.net/blog/2011/05/customizing-android-listview-item-layout/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think this is useful to you , call simple adapter with two string array

```
public class simleAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private Context mContext;
private LayoutInflater linflater;
private TextView txt_1, txt_2;
private String[] str1;
private String[] str2;

public simleAdapter(Context context, String[] s1, String[] s2) {
    mContext = context;
    str1 = s1;
    str2 = s2;
    linflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return str1.length;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int arg0) {
    return str1[arg0];
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int arg0) {
    return arg0;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    if (convertView == null) {

        convertView = linflater.inflate(R.layout.feed_raw, null);

    }

    txt_1 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtlist1);
    txt_2 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtlist2);
    txt_1.setText(str1[position]);
    txt_2.setText(str2[position]);

    return convertView;

}
```

}

let me know if you have any doubt here

Comment: what about the second string array? I mean the methods getCount and getItem are not being used for str2 right?

Comment: the length of two array should be same , otherwise you have to used the arraylist of object. make a class with two string member and pass arraylist og those class object to the adapter

Comment: Thank u but I've found a great tutorial which is similar to yours. Worked for me.

Comment: ok No problem but there is any relation between two string array then you should use object's arraylist it is much easier and faster

Comment: @Dinesh can you give a link to the tutorial which you found, please?

Answer (score 0):

Check my answer in this thread [Custom adapter: get item number of clicked item in inflated listview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9151630/custom-adapter-get-item-number-of-clicked-item-in-inflated-listview/9151901#9151901).
That should answer what you are trying to do.

Comment: thanks, but I can hardly find any similarity between what I'm trying to do and the your answer in the above thread.

Comment: The original poster has two string arrays as well. So I turned it into one object and manage it that way.

Comment: I want both of them to be different.