# OnclickListner on a custom listview adapter

Tags: android, android-listview, android-view, onclicklistener, baseadapter

I am newbie to Android so you can expect this a little silly but please do help.
I have somewhat like custom `listviews` of people similar to *whatsapp* and other *IM apps* etc.

Now when i click the `listview` i want to get the respective `id` of the clicked `listview`. 
How can i possibly do that ?
Where will i put the `onclicklistner`  method ?

**CustomListAdapter.java**

```
package com.example.soc.adater;

import com.example.soc.R;
import com.example.soc.model.IMList;
import com.example.soc.util.ImageLoadTask;

import java.util.List;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class CustomListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Activity activity;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private List<IMList> listItems;
    //ImageLoader imageLoader = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();

    public CustomListAdapter(Activity activity, List<IMList> listItems) {
        this.activity = activity;
        this.listItems = listItems;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return listItems.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int location) {
        return listItems.get(location);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        if (inflater == null)
            inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        if (convertView == null)
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row, null);

        //if (imageLoader == null)
            //imageLoader = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();
        ImageView pp = (ImageView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.pp);
        TextView pname = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.pname);
        TextView uname = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.uname);
        TextView msgcon = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.msgcon);
        TextView msgtime = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.msgtime);

        // getting movie data for the row
        IMList m = listItems.get(position);

        // thumbnail image
        //pp.setImageUrl(m.getppUrl(), imageLoader);
         new ImageLoadTask(m.getppUrl(), pp).execute();

        // name
        pname.setText(m.getpname());

        // @username
        uname.setText(String.valueOf(m.getuname()));

        // msgcontent
        msgcon.setText(m.getmsgcon());

        // messageTime
        msgtime.setText(String.valueOf(m.getmsgtime()));        
        return convertView;
    }


}
```

Comment: Do you want to get the ListView id when you click on any item, or when you click on the ListView itself?

Comment: when i click a `Listview item` @programmer23

Comment: I edited my answer once check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your activity after setting adapter to listview call

```
yourListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long id) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            //based on position you can get id
        }
    });
```

**EDIT :**

To get clicked user details in ListView use

```
convertView.setTag(m) in getView() of CustomAdapter
```

then in setOnItemClickListener of ListView call

```
IMList obj=(IMList)arg1.getTag();
```

Hope this will helps you.

Comment: It says `create class OnItemClickListener`

Comment: Import that class by using ctrl+shift+o if you are using eclipse.

Comment: `the method setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {}); `is undefined for List<IMlist> where IMList is my custom addapter

Comment: you have to set setOnItemClickListener for ListView not List.

Answer (score 2):

Use setOnItemClickListener() of listview.
You have to use this method in Your MainActivity class where your Listview is defined

```
 listView.setOnItemClickListener(new android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,int position, long   id) {
String item = contests_listView.getItemAtPosition(position);
Toast.makeText(this,"You selected : " + item,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();                
         }
      });
```

the position variable will return id of selected item.

Comment: call this method with Listview object

Comment: OK but how will i get the `user_id` ? If say i clicked a `listview` of a *particular user*  then how will i get the clicked user's `user_id` @guddu ?

Comment: check onItemClick method,In that you have four parameter parent, view,position, id,

You can use this parameter.

Check this answer by RobGThai

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9151630/custom-adapter-get-item-number-of-clicked-item-in-inflated-listview


Check how the PlaceAdapter  is written.
Hope this will Help you.

Comment: or Please check This example
http://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/android/data/adapters/create_a_custom_adapter_for_contacts/

Answer (score 2):

```
the_list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            //Use this if you want to get the whole ListView id
            parent.getId();

            //or use this if you want the item id
             view.getId()
        }
    });
```

Comment: What's the difference? I really thought that using view.getId() would work, but it turned out that parent.getId() was  what I needed. Thank you!

Comment: The parent parameter is the ListView. The view parameter is the item clicked.

Answer (score 1):

You should put the onClickListener in the Activity.

```
  your_list.OnItemClickListener = new MyOnClickListenerClass();
```

and create also the class

```
 public class MyOnClickListenerClass: Java.Lang.Object, AdapterView.IOnItemClickListener
{

    public void OnItemClick(AdapterView parent, View view, int position, long id)
    {
       //do stuf 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is another method for the listView: onItemClickListener

```
listview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View item,
            int position, long id) {
          //this code will be fired after clicking on listview item

    }
});
```